# How to replace elements and stub methods in Polymer

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, testing, polymer, polymer-2.x

In my unit tests, I would like to be able to replace elements with mocked elements and also provide stubs for methods of the original element.

For example, let's say the template of my component is like this:

```
<template>
   <my-other-element id="myOtherElement"></my-other-element>
</template>
```

Let's say later in my element I do something like this:

```
myMethod: function () {
   this.$.myOtherElement.foo();
}
```

When I write the unit test for my element, I would like to do the following:

1. Mock the entire `<my-other-element>`
2. Provide a stub method for `foo()`

I have found a way to achieve this but somehow it does not seem to be very clean. My current solution is the following:

```
var fooStub;

beforeEach(function () {
    fooStub = sinon.stub();

    replace('my-other-element').with('fake-my-other-element');
    document.createElement('fake-my-other-element').constructor.prototype = {
        foo: fooStub
    };
    element = fixture('basic');
});
```

I am wondering if there is a better way to achieve the same results. Somehow creating an empty element in order to change the `prototype` property to add stubs does not seem to be the best way.

And I know you can also do this:

```
stub('my-other-element', {
    foo: fooStub
});
```

But I prefer to always mock everything in advance to make sure there are no side-effects coming from the child element.

Answer (score 1):

there are a few options I've used. One is to proactively add those methods to the element in question

```
chai.should();
suite('let\s stub a child method', () => {
  let testView;
  setup(() => {
    replace('child-el').with('fake-child-el');
    testView = fixture('basic');
    testView.$.child.method = sinon.stub();
  });

  test('myMethod() calls child method', () => {
    testView.myMethod();
    testView.$.child.method.should.have.been.called;
  });
});
```

Another is to create a fake element to stub with and wrap it's methods

```
Polymer({is: 'fake-child-el', method: sinon.stub;});

chai.should();
suite('let\s stub a child method', () => {
  let testView;
  setup(() => {
    replace('child-el').with('fake-child-el');
    testView = fixture('basic');
  });

  test('myMethod() calls child method', () => {
    testView.myMethod();
    testView.$.child.method.should.have.been.called;
  });
});
```

This might not work in all browsers.

EDIT: in cases where the second approach failed, I've made the stub-element's methods something like `method: () => null`, and then wrapped that method in a sinon.stub() call inside the test suite.

Comment: Thanks Benny. Your first option was my preferred way before. But if you call a method from the child component in the `ready()` or `attached()` callbacks, you can't mock the methods like that.

The Second option might work as well. Maybe that's the cleanest.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I tried the second method:
`Polymer({is: 'fake-child-el', method: sinon.stub;});`

It works but the statement can only be executed once (as a Polymer element can be neither unregistered nor registered a second time), and you may want to call it more than once (for example, to change `method`'s return value). To work around this, you can do the following:

```
let fakeChildEl;  
let replaceChildEl = (methodReturnVal) => {
  const methodStub = sandbox.stub().returns(methodReturnVal);
  fakeChildEl = Polymer({
    is: 'fake-child-el',
    method: methodStub,
  });
  replace('child-el').with('fake-child-el');

  replaceChildEl = (methodReturnVal) => {
    const methodStub = sandbox.stub().returns(methodReturnVal);
    fakeChildEl.prototype.method = methodStub;
    replace('child-el').with('fake-child-el');
  }
};
```

Then any unit test can call `replaceChildEl(variableReturnVal)`